How to eliminate the overhead of utilizing threadpools in nested for-loops
I am trying to multithread the p2-loop in the inner loop of the following nested loops in C++. I don't want the outer loop to be multithreaded due to shared data.
// OUTER LOOP
for ( int l = 0; l < NT; l++ ) {
    for ( int k = 0; k < NZ; k++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < NY; j++ ) {
            for ( int i = 0; i < NX; i++ ) {
    
                // define pStart and pEnd
                // ...
                
                // INNER LOOP (a 16x16x16 loop and it takes 20us on a single thread)   
                for ( int p2 = p2Start; p2 < p2End; p2++ ) {
                    for ( int p1 = p1Start; p1 < p1End; p1++ ) {
                        for ( int p0 = p0Start; p0 < p0End; p0++ ) {            
                            // performing inner loop computation...
                            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(20));
                        }
                    }
                }

I have tried bshoshany/thread-pool:
BS::thread_pool pool;
BS::multi_future<void> loop_future = pool.submit_loop(p2Start, p2End, [&](int p2) {
    for ( int p1 = p1Start; p1 < p1End; p1++ ) {
        for ( int p0 = p0Start; p0 < p0End; p0++ ) {
            // performing inner loop computation...
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(20));
        }
    }
});

as well as Intel TBB parallel_for and they both have a huge overhead and significantly increase 20us with no gained benefits.
tbb::parallel_for(p2Start, p2End, [&](int p2) {
    for ( int p1 = p1Start; p1 < p1End; p1++ ) {
        for ( int p0 = p0Start; p0 < p0End; p0++ ) {
            // performing inner loop computation...
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(20));
        }
    }
});

Is there any way to efficiently use multiple threads for this task with very minimal overhead to gain speedup?

Impossible to say what your problem is without a [mcve] (the "inner loop computation" might matter a ton if it screws up your cache lines).  [Edit] your question or use a profiler and see what you can figure out, but right now we can only guess.

Parallelizing a code lasting for 20 µs does not make sense to me. Once parallelized, the code should reach 1-10 µs but the overhead of thread communication is often >1 µs so it will be significant. The overhead of scheduling can be significantly higher than 1 µs. A barrier often takes at least several hundreds of nanoseconds at best. Sometimes much more on some servers (e.g. 1-100 µs). The higher the number of core, the higher the overhead. This means this code will not scale.

The key to speed this code is to optimize the inner loop if you cannot find any coarse-grained source of (core-based) parallelism. Is it vectorizable using SIMD instruction? Is it already vectorized? Can you improve the instruction-level parallelism (ILP)? Can you use better suited instructions? Can you pre-compute/post-compute some parts in parallel using multiple threads so to reduce the sequential?

By the way, sleeping functions are really bad for parallel benchmark as they often do not last for the specified time at this granularity since most OS scheduler cannot reach such a granularity. On Windows for example, the granularity is generally 1 ms. Besides, threads are often not even scheduled to 10 threads sleeping can be executed concurrently on a 1 core CPU which means you can conclude the execution is 10 times faster with 10 threads while it is not.

The MCVE has a 4096 loop each taking 20us, or about 0.08s total.  The parallel one launches 16 threads each doing 256 20us sleeps, each thread taking 0.005s.
